# Can not be inherited from a template C++ class

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

I don't know what is the problem here... Maybe someone can help me, please.
I want to inherit my new class `MyDictionary` from template abstract class `dictionary`.
I have exactly this code:

**Dictionary.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_CPP_DICTIONARY_H
#define UNTITLED_CPP_DICTIONARY_H

template<class Key, class Value>
class dictionary {
public:
    virtual ~dictionary() = default;

    virtual const Value &get(const Key &key) const = 0;

    virtual void set(const Key &key, const Value &value) = 0;

    virtual bool is_set(const Key &key) const = 0;
};

template<class Key>
class not_found_exception : public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const Key &get_key() const noexcept = 0;
};

#endif //UNTITLED_CPP_DICTIONARY_H
```

**MyDictionary.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_CPP_MYDICTIONARY_H
#define UNTITLED_CPP_MYDICTIONARY_H

#include "dictionary.h"

template<class Key, class Value>
class MyDictionary : public dictionary {
public:
    const Value &get(const Key &key) const;
    void set(const Key &key, const Value &value);
    bool is_set(const Key &key) const;

    ~MyDictionary() = default;
};


#endif //UNTITLED_CPP_MYDICTIONARY_H
```

I am using CLion 2021.2 and the compiler MinGW 5.4, that saying like this:

```
====================[ Build | untitled_cpp | Debug ]============================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Projects\untitled_cpp\cmake-build-debug --target untitled_cpp -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target untitled_cpp
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/MyDictionary.cpp.obj
In file included from D:\Projects\untitled_cpp\MyDictionary.cpp:1:
D:\Projects\untitled_cpp\MyDictionary.h:7:40: error: expected class-name before '{' token
    7 | class MyDictionary : public dictionary {
      |                                        ^
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/MyDictionary.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [untitled_cpp] Error 2
CMakeFiles\untitled_cpp.dir\build.make:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/MyDictionary.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled_cpp.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'untitled_cpp' failed
```

There is no helpful information about the problem. And I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: You need to inherit `public dictionary<Key, Value>`.

Comment: @Анна Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dictionary` is a **class template**, and therefore when you inherit from it you have to specify the template arguments.

In your case it seems like you would like to inherit `dictionary` with the same template arguments used for the derived class.

**Therefore change:**

```
class MyDictionary : public dictionary {
```

**To:**

```
//------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvv
class MyDictionary : public dictionary<Key, Value> {
```

Comment: Could've closed this as dupe. There are plenty of dupes for this.

Comment: @Kal - My main focus is to answer questions that I can help with. I admit I put less effort on searching for dupes (I mainly stumble upon them when searching for info related to questions if I need to).

Comment: Dupes should be closed according to SO's guidelines and instructions by moderators.

Comment: It's OK to vote to close a dupe. I do it myself sometimes. But it doesn't mean that a contributer like me that would like to help and answer _must_ do it before answering. It is actually the duty of the OP that posted the question to search thoroughly. Also keep in mind there are border cases or partial overlaps between posts. Anyway - this is at least how I understood the guidelines. Can you refer me to a specific guideline link that suggests otherwise ?